# Use cat output in another program with pipe in C

Tags: c, unix, pipe, cat, piping

I want to run: `cat` somefile | `program` > outputText in a UNIX system.

I have looked at many things such as pipe, using popen, dup2, etc; I am lost.

Basic code should be:

- Read whatever output `cat` produces using `program` and do some magic, an then output the data into outputText.

Any advice please?

**P.S.**
The files are binary files.

**UPDATE:**

I found this code that works with the prescribed command above... But
 it does things I don't want.

1. How do I get rid of the `sort`? I tried erasing things, but then I get errors and the program doesn't run.
2. Read data by `cat` as binary
3. Output data to terminal as binary

Any tips please?

```
int main(void)
{
    pid_t p;
    int status;
    int fds[2];
    FILE *writeToChild;
    char word[50];

    if (pipe(fds) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error creating pipes");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    switch (p = fork())
    {
        case 0: //this is the child process
            close(fds[1]); //close the write end of the pipe
            dup2(fds[0], 0);
            close(fds[0]);
            execl("/usr/bin/sort", "sort", (char *) 0);
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to exec sort\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        case -1: //failure to fork case
            perror("Could not create child");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        default: //this is the parent process
            close(fds[0]); //close the read end of the pipe
            writeToChild = fdopen(fds[1], "w");
            break;
    }

    if (writeToChild != 0)
    {
        while (fscanf(stdin, "%49s", word) != EOF)
        {
            //the below isn't being printed.  Why?
            fprintf(writeToChild, "%s end of sentence\n", word);
        }
        fclose(writeToChild);
    }

    wait(&status);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `cat` to pipe into it when you can just set the `stdin` of `program` to `somefile`? i.e., `program < somefile > outputText`

Comment: My task specifies I must do it this way unfortunately.

Comment: And the file read by cat is binary, and the output should be binary as well if possible.

Comment: Do I need to have 2 files? One file does the piping? I noticed that many programs make calls to exec(), where they call a specific file, in my case that would be program? So pipe.c would call program.c and somehow take stdout from cat and place it into program.c???

Comment: If you, as you say, is supposed to (homework?) run the program as `cat somefile | program > output`, then you're on the wrong track. Running the command like that makes the shell *pipe* the output from `cat` to the input of `program`. That's not the same as setting up a pipe inside your program. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)#Piping

Comment: Its a coding exercise for a club contest. Anyway, I have to follow this script format. I got some things working with the code I posted so far, but still not perfect. @Henrik, that's exactly what I want, to pipe output of `cat` to `stdin` of `program`!

Comment: And is your program the same as `program` in the command?

Comment: @Henrik, `program` or call it whatever, "textAlteration" is supposed to alter the input of `stdin`, which is fed from `cat`.

Comment: Then all you need to do is to read from `stdin`.

Comment: Wow, you are amazing @Henrik!!!! I spent around 9 hours trying to "pipe" stuff. I didn't understand it to begin with, but after seeing these comments from you guys, I finally realized that piping means to link to commands together or call another program inside your program.

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion, as you wanted read and write binary files:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    if (!freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin)) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (!freopen(NULL, "wb", stdout)) {
        return 1;
    }

    char buf[4];
    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        size_t numbytes = fread(buf, 1, 4, stdin);

        // Do something with the bytes here...

        fwrite(buf, 1, numbytes, stdout);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I just did :).. Took a while to figure out how to make stdout output binary. Wish I looked at this 20 min ago.

Comment: The EOF check is out of order. You should check `feof()` after the `fread()` but before the `fwrite()`.  Or just use the return value of `fread()`.

Comment: @FatalError From the `fread` man-page: "If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero)." I.e. `numbytes` holds the number of bytes actually read, even if `EOF` was reached. These bytes need to be written.

Comment: @Henrik: +1 Yeah, now that I look more closely your code is correct. If the read fails to return any data it will call `fwrite()` with 0 bytes, so it won't actually write anything that's in `buf`.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to read the output (stdout) of `cat`, you don't need to pipe anything I found thanks to you guys! I got sidetracked with piping...

so if you run " `cat` somefile | `program` ", where *somefile* contains binary data...
you will just see whatever somefile contains, reprinted on a terminal.

Thank you! Now I can finish writing my `program`.

```
/*program.c*/

int main()
{
    int i, num;

    unsigned char block[2];

    while ((num = fread(block, 1, 2, stdin)) == 2)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            printf("%02x", block[i]);
        }
    }

}
```